# yii2 Not Found (#404)

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

I have created new controller in the project but I am getting Not Found (#404) error when I try to access it.
I am using the following URL
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=users/index

here is the controller:

```
<?php
namespace app\Controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Users;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
      public function actionIndex()
    {
        $users= Users::find()->all();
        return $this->render('index',['users'=>$users]);
    }
}
?>
```

and here is the model:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Users extends ActiveRecord{

}
?>
```

and here is the view:

```
<?php
    foreach($users as $user){
        echo $user->username."<br/>";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved, the error accorded because "Controller" shouldn't start with capital letter in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=users/indexe , because i see that your indec function in controller is  `public function actionIndexe()`

Comment: Yeah, I have corrected that but it's not the reason of the problem; the reason was writing the word "Controller" with capital letter in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In Case of Advance, The namespace app must be change to frontend in addition to the Basel.shoban comment. like this **frontend\controllers**.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The OP posted a different solution for this problem